# Install QScintilla to qtpy

Tags: qscintilla, qtpy

I am using qtpy to write Qt application and I import modules as `

```
from qtpy import QtWidget
```

I would like to install QScintilla but installing it using

```
pip install QScintilla
```

installs  QScintilla inside *site-packages/PyQt5* directory ,but I would like it go to *site-packages/qtpy* , if possible.

I have also tried

```
pip install --target site-packages/qtpy QScintilla
```

but it install PyQt5 first inside *site-packages/qtpy* directory (as dependency) and inside Qscintilla inside the new PyQt5 directory.

Comment: It makes no sense to use QScintilla with qtpy, because PySide currently does not provide any bindings for it. If you want to use QScintilla, you should use a pure PyQt project.

Comment: I think, that makes a lot of sense! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this commit](https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtpy/commit/e7a70602f8999d79857963055d44bbc1c6c87674), the QScinitilla can be imported from qtpy as

```
from qtpy import Qsci
```